# After Phone Verification Application stops running and give me an error. Kotlin Firebase

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

This is my activity i am trying to go on home activity after phone number verification but app is crashing and I don't know why. i have connected 2 app on firebase one is driver side and second this one is rider side Driver side works correctly. but on this case it says phone number requires verification. i have added phone numbers manually in firebase

[image]

```
package com.example.driveeaserider

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.driveeaserider.Common.Common
import com.example.driveeaserider.Model.RiderModel
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthMethodPickerLayout
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI
import com.firebase.ui.auth.IdpResponse
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import io.reactivex.Completable
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
import java.util.Arrays
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class SplashScreenActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    companion object {
        private val LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE = 7171
    }

    lateinit var provider: List<AuthUI.IdpConfig>
    lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
    lateinit var listener: FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener

    private lateinit var database: FirebaseDatabase
    private lateinit var riderInfoRef: DatabaseReference

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        delaySplashScreen()
    }

    private fun delaySplashScreen() {
        Completable.timer(3,TimeUnit.SECONDS,AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(listener)
            })
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        if (firebaseAuth != null && listener != null) firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(listener)
        super.onStop()
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen)

        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        riderInfoRef = database.getReference(Common.RIDER_INFO_REFERENCE)
        provider = Arrays.asList(
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
        )
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        listener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { myFirebaseAuth ->
            val user = myFirebaseAuth.currentUser
            if(user != null)
            {
                checkUserFromFirebase()
            }
            else
            {
                showLoginLayout()
            }
        }

    }

    private fun showLoginLayout() {
        val authMethodPickerLayout = AuthMethodPickerLayout.Builder(R.layout.activity_sign_in)
            .setPhoneButtonId(R.id.btn_phone_sign_in)
            .setGoogleButtonId(R.id.btn_google_sign_in)
            .build()

        startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAuthMethodPickerLayout(authMethodPickerLayout)
            .setTheme(R.style.SignInTheme)
            .setAvailableProviders(provider)
            .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
            .build(), LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE
        )
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(requestCode == LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            val response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data)
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(this@SplashScreenActivity,response!!.error!!.message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    private fun checkUserFromFirebase() {
        riderInfoRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object:ValueEventListener{
                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                    if(p0.exists())
                    {
                        val model = p0.getValue(RiderModel::class.java)
                        goToHomeActivity(model)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        showRegisterLayout()
                    }
                }

                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@SplashScreenActivity,p0.message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

            })
    }

    private fun showRegisterLayout() {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.DialogTheme)
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_register,null)

        val edt_first_name = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.edt_first_name) as TextInputEditText
        val edt_last_name = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.edt_last_name) as TextInputEditText
        val edt_phone_number = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.edt_phone_number) as TextInputEditText
        val progressBar = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progress_bar)

        val btn_continue = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.btn_register) as Button

        //Set Data
        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.phoneNumber != null &&
            !TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.phoneNumber))
            edt_phone_number.setText(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.phoneNumber)

        //View
        builder.setView(itemView)
        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()

        //Event
        btn_continue.setOnClickListener{
            if(TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(edt_first_name.text.toString()))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this@SplashScreenActivity,"Please Enter First Name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            else
                if(TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(edt_last_name.text.toString()))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this@SplashScreenActivity,"Please Enter Last Name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    return@setOnClickListener

                }
                else
                    if(TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(edt_phone_number.text.toString()))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this@SplashScreenActivity,"Please Enter Phone Number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        return@setOnClickListener
                    }

                    else {
                        val model = RiderModel()
                        model.firstName = edt_first_name.text.toString()
                        model.lastName = edt_last_name.text.toString()
                        model.phoneNumber = edt_phone_number.text.toString()


                        riderInfoRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
                            .setValue(model)
                            .addOnFailureListener{ e ->
                                Toast.makeText(this@SplashScreenActivity,"" + e.message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                dialog.dismiss()
                                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE





                            }
                            .addOnSuccessListener {
                                Toast.makeText(this@SplashScreenActivity,"Register Successfully!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                dialog.dismiss()

                                goToHomeActivity(model)

                                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE


                            }

                    }
        }
    }

    private fun goToHomeActivity(model: RiderModel?) {
        Common.currentRider = model
        startActivity(Intent(this,HomeActivity::class.java))
        finish()

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you see this [issue](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1591)? Does it help?

Comment: ye i saw it but not helpful at all